# How to install CMake to install PyTorch in root without root authorization

Tags: python, linux, openssl, pytorch

I'm installing pytorch in Linux on a slurm cluster. Since I don't have `sudo` authorization, I have to install everything from source code.

I'm using the following codes for the PyTorch installation:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
$ sed -i 's/-pPR/-PR/' ~/torch/exe/luajit-rocks/luarocks/src/luarocks/fs/unix/tools.lua
$ cd ~/torch; ./install.sh
```

While I'm running the `cd ~/torch; ./install.sh` command, I got the following error:

```
Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21
./install.sh: line 73: cmake: command not found
```

So my job becomes installing `cmake`. I followed [this post](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_cmake_on_linux.php):

```
$ wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.3.tar.gz
$ tar xzf cmake-2.8.3.tar.gz
$ cd cmake-2.8.3
$ ./configure --help
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/cmake
```

While when I run the last line, I got :

```
 Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:511 (message):
  Could not find OpenSSL.  Install an OpenSSL development package or
  configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.
```

And though I installed OpenSSL, and have `OpenSSL has been successfully configured`, the same `Could NOT find OpenSSL` happens. Everything would be easy if I have the `sudo` authorization, but I would like to know how to install without it.

Comment: How did you install OpenSSL?  The cmake configuration file looks for libcrypto and libssl.  Are they someplace cmake could find them?   Do you really need OpenSSL?  The error tells you how to build cmake without it.